# How do you render a javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code, but when I try to use it on the 3rd line, I get `[object HTMLHeadingElement]` in the HTML output. How do I take the whole HTML of `x` and prepend it to `y.innerHTML`?

```
x = document.getElementById("region-footer-first").getElementsByClassName("block-title")[0];
y = document.getElementById("region-footer-first").getElementsByClassName("jcarousel-clip")[0];

y.innerHTML = x + y.innerHTML;
```

Comment: One does not simply render an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the entire contents of `x`, including its tags, use `.outerHTML`, like this

```
x = document.getElementById("region-footer-first").getElementsByClassName("block-title")[0];

y = document.getElementById("region-footer-first").getElementsByClassName("jcarousel-clip")[0];

y.innerHTML = x.outerHTML + y.innerHTML;
```

Comment: but i'm only grabbing the HTML inside that. I want the entire x output added to y.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'the entire x output'

Comment: Did you mean outerHTML?

Comment: x = <h2>blah</h2> ... if i did x.innerHTML = blah ... but i want the entire output which is <h2>blah</h2>

Comment: @duckx - `x.outerHTML`

Comment: @scrblnrd3 - I think you mean `y.innerHTML = x.outerHTML + y.innerHTML;`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 haha whoops. Thanks for catching that